# TransitionGroup lag when using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, requestanimationframe

### Description

I'm creating the following app logic:

- There is a list of checkable items with a specific price for each.
- There is a calculated total price for checked items.

I'm also animating the number change for the total price using the `requestAnimationFrame`.
So far so good, the number animation itself works fine.

### Problem

However, my `TransitionGroup` move transition starts to lag when I have the following element structure:

```
<Transition>
  <div>
    {{ animatedNumber }}
    <TransitionGroup>
      ...
    </TransitionGroup>
  </div>
</Transition>
```

### Notes

- Seems that there is some conflict between the `Transition` elements and `requestAnimationFrame`.
- The `TransitionGroup` move animation works fine if I remove the parent `Transition` element.
- The `TransitionGroup` move animation works fine if I remove the number counter based on `requestAnimationFrame`.
- This issue happens only on Chrome.

### Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-a4hnef?file=src/components/App.vue

Comment: Why do you need this requestAnimationFrame manipulations at all? The transition works well and smooth without it. You intention is not clear.

Comment: @Tolbxela How do you animate the number change using transitions?

Comment: Ok, I see now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test the performance of your app. You can follow the following steps:

```
Open chrome dev tool -> performance -> click record -> make animation by checking to a checkbox -> click stop
```

The result should look like that:

[image]

Zooming into a task you will see:

[image]

As we can see each task is caused by the `componentUpdateFn`. That is because, in every animation frame, you update the variable and force Vue to re-render the template. It's too much work. To make your animation smooth, each animation frame should run in a 16ms time frame (60fps)

To solve your problem you should put in less work as possible in each animation frame by:

- optimizing your `animate` function
- if you want to update your view in every frame, you should do it by pure JS instead of using Vue

This is the [optimal version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-awk4f2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FApp.vue) of your code. I just use JS to update the animating number. It's not perfect but it much better than the original version.

```js
// in the script. update the view by pure JS
watch(animatedTotalPrice, () => {
  totalPriceElm.value.innerText = animatedTotalPrice.value;
});
// in the template, DON'T let Vue do the updating work
<h3 ref="totalPriceElm" v-once>{{ animatedTotalPrice }} USD</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigation and the optimized code, works like a charm!