# Each change on state destroys user input if one-way bound

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Consider a simple clock display and an input which I bound one-way to keep control over old/new state:

```html
<div>{{ time }}</div>
<input ref="text" type="text" :value="text" style="width:95%">
<button type="button" @click="saveOnDiff">Save</button>
```

```js
createApp({
  ...,
  methods: {
    saveOnDiff() {
      const current = this.$refs.text.value;
      // Compare current with old text + update if it changed.
      ...
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const instance = this;
    setInterval(() => instance.time = new Date(), 1000);
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

The clock is updated each second. Unfortunately, this update spoils the input. Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/dL78tsh9

**How can I reduce binding updates to the absolute necessary ones?** Some extra switch on one-way bindings like `:value.lazy="text"` would be helpful...

Comment: Pretty sure there are quite a of those "timer" questions here already. Maybe give it a search.

Comment: @kissu This question is not about a timer.

Comment: @Marcel Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to fix it is to use [`v-memo="[text]"`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-memo):

```js
<input ref="text" type="text" :value="text" style="width:95%" v-memo="[text]">
```

**The `<input>` will only be updated when my `text` property has updated and not the any other property like the `time` property.**

Test here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dL78tsh9/47/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to trick VueJs to not re-render a specific field.

When the time changes, your existing virtual DOM has a value for "text" and the newly generated virtual DOM has a different value so... VueJS re renders it.

### UPDATE:

Based on @Tolbxela comment, looks like you could use v-once to only render the field once, and ignore the future DOM updates.

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-once

### Alternative

If you want to control old/new state, why don't you just use two-way binding and save both states?

Something like this:

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue

const characterWiseDiff = (left, right) => right
  .split("")
  .filter(function(character, index) {
    return character != left.charAt(index);
  })
  .join("");


createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      result: "",
      text: "Try to change me here",
      previousText: "Try to change me here",
      time: new Date(),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveOnDiff() {
      if (this.text === this.previousText) {
        this.result = "No changes have been made!";
      } else {
        this.result = `Saved! Your changes were: "${characterWiseDiff(this.previousText, this.text)}"`;
        this.previousText = this.text;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const instance = this;
    setInterval(() => instance.time = new Date(), 1000);
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div>{{ time }}</div>
  <div>
    <input id="mockId" ref="text" type="text" v-model="text" style="width:95%">
    <button type="button" @click="saveOnDiff">Save</button>
  </div>
  {{ result }}

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmxLuf9w/6/

Comment: There is the `v-once` https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-once directive, to render an element and component once only

Comment: Didn't know about that one! But that sounds like a potential solution for this issue. Thanks for sharing! :D

Comment: @FacundoGallardo Shadow copying properties isn't a fancy solution. But instead `v-once` you could add `v-memo="[text]"` to the input. That should do the trick. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `time` on each and every second will cause the whole template to be re-run after every 1 second. Which results everything in that template getting updated.

When a user types into `<input>` element, You aren't storing that value anywhere. You've got a `:value` to poke the value in but you aren't updating it when the value changes. The result will be that when Vue re-renders everything it will jump back to its original value.

**Possible solution :** Kindly ensure that your data is kept in sync with what the user types in. This could be done using `v-model` and watcher to get new and old values and based on that you can achieve this requirmeent.

You can try something like this (This is not a perfect solution but it will give you an idea) **:**

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue

const characterWiseDiff = (left, right) => right
  .split("")
  .filter(function(character, index) {
    return character != left.charAt(index);
  })
  .join("");


createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      result: "",
      text: "Try to change me here",
      time: new Date(),
      oldVal: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    text(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.oldVal = oldVal;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveOnDiff() {
      if (!this.oldVal) this.oldVal = this.text
      const current = this.$refs.text.value;
      console.log(current, this.oldVal)
      if (current === this.oldVal) {
        this.result = "No changes have been made!";
      } else {
        this.result = `Saved! Your changes were: "${characterWiseDiff(current, this.oldVal)}"`;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const instance = this;
    setInterval(() => instance.time = new Date(), 1000);
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.41/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div>{{ time }}</div>
  <input ref="text" type="text" v-model="text" style="width:95%">
  <button type="button" @click="saveOnDiff">Save</button>
  {{ result }}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to not use the Vue reactivity for timer updates at all. See my **UPDATE 2** below.

The simplest way to fix it is to replace `:value` with `v-model`

**UPDATE 1:**

We need an other data field to store the `input` value.

```
<input ref="text" type="text" v-model="input" style="width:95%">
```

Check the sample below.

But it is not a good solution for complex apps, since every second you whole app HTML is refreshed. This can cause problems with rendering and lags.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have missed the other logic of comparing values. Here is the well working solution

**UPDATE 2:**

This question helped me to understand the whole problem with template rendering in Vue.

[TransitionGroup lag when using requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74288418/2487565)

And here is a good article about [Improve Vue Performance with v-once + v-memo](https://learnvue.co/tutorials/v-once-v-memo)

**CODE:**

```js
const placeholder = "Try to change me here"

const {
  createApp
} = Vue

const characterWiseDiff = (left, right) => right
  .split("")
  .filter(function(character, index) {
    return character != left.charAt(index);
  })
  .join("");


createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      result: "",
      text: placeholder,
      input: placeholder,
      time: new Date(),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveOnDiff() {
      const current = this.input
      if (current === this.text) {
        this.result = "No changes have been made!";
      } else {
        this.result = `Saved! Your changes were: "${characterWiseDiff(this.text, current)}"`;
        this.text = current;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const instance = this;
    setInterval(() => instance.time = new Date(), 1000);
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <div>{{ time }}</div>
  <input ref="text" type="text" v-model="input" style="width:95%">
  <button type="button" @click="saveOnDiff">Save</button>
  {{ result }}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now it won't recognize the changes the user made.

Comment: @Amini you are right. I have missed the other logic. The answer was fixed.

Comment: Now it won't show the result :)

Comment: @Amini yes, but I would say the comparing function is bad coded. The both variants does not show all changes. The solution with the `previousText` field does not show the deleted characters otherwise.